# Proving that a homomorphism between two rings is surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

The problem: ($\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of real valued functions)

> Let $\phi:\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by $\phi(f)=(f(0),f(1))$ Prove that $\phi$ is a surjective homomorphism from $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, and describe its kernel.

I showed that $\phi$ is a homomorphism in the following way:

> Let $f,g\in\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})$. Then $$
> \begin{align}
> \phi\left(f+g\right)&=(f(0)+g(0),f(1)+g(1))\\
> &=(f(0),f(1))+(g(0),g(1))\\
> &=\phi(f)+\phi(g)
> \end{align}
> $$
>   The operation of multiplication is shown in a similar fashion.

Anyways, assuming that's correct, I assume the next step is to show that the function is *onto*, and finally finding $\ker(\phi)$.

How is the proof of surjectivity shown? Usually, I'm dealing with a function like $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ so it's easy to solve for $x$, for example. But the codomain of this function $\phi$ are ordered pairs?

From there, will finding the kernel be rather trivial? Or do you have hints for that as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rest is straightforward.

**$\phi$ is a surjection:** If $(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2$, define $f\in \mathscr{F}$ by
$$\begin{align}
f(0) &= x \\
f(1) &= y \\
f(z) &= 0 \text{ if $z\ne x, z\ne y$}. \\
\end{align}$$
Then $\phi(f) = (x,y)$.

**The kernel of $\phi$** is all $f$ such that $\phi(f) = (0,0)$, as $(0,0)$ is the $\mathbf{0}$ of the ring $\Bbb R^2$. This should be easy to characterize.

Comment: Thanks for liking my answer so much, you posted an identical one several minutes later.

Comment: @StellaBiderman Yeah, I need to crib from you. I was writing while you were, and I don't look up when I do, especially not to look at another answer. Here, have a +1.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. We want to show that there exists a function such that $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=y$. Define $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ piece-wise by these two expression, and let $f(z)=0$ at all other points. This is a function, so it's subjective.

The kernel is exactly the set of functions that satisfy $f(0)=f(1)=0$